# Create Mac .app file: How to set the WorkingDirectory to parent path?

Tags: java, macos, jar

I am using Mac's Jar Bundler to create a (.app) file for my Java application. My java application consists of a jar file + a couple of folders. I want to put the jar file inside the .app file, but keep the folders outside the .app file. Is this possible ?

I see the default resources path is **Contents/Resources/Java** inside the .app file, so can this be set to the parent path of the .app file ?

Comment: Is you problem solve? If yes! Can you help me out, Now I'm facing same problem.Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639175/derby-appdata-not-found-by-desktopos-jar-when-im-try-to-create-a-mac-os-x-appl

Answer (score 3):

Among the [*Java Dictionary Info.plist Keys*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001969), `$APP_PACKAGE` "expands into the path to the root directory of the application bundle." Alternatively, consider creating copies of your folder data in `$USER_HOME` or [`Preferences`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i want the folders to appear on the same path of the app file, so when the user runs the DMG file he will see the .app file + a group of files which he can access easily when necessary.

Comment: That's probably OK for read-only data or a single, administrative user; but I'm not sure it would scale well.